# Airflow Operational error sqlalquemy (sqlite3.OperationalError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm trying to install airflow, and I get this error when I try to create the db or run standalone. I tried to change the version of sqlalchemy but it didn't work.

os: manjaro |
sqlalchemy version: 1.4 |
airflow version: 2.3.0

```
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, Add 
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: operator

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: operator
[SQL: ALTER TABLE task_instance ADD COLUMN operator VARCHAR(1000)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Something to fix it?

Comment: you can find the answer in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988054/apache-airflow-initdb-fails-at-kubernetes-resource-checkingpoint-for-mysql

Answer (score 2):

what I found I checked out the code files pointed out by 'Shi Chen' two files are responsible for this behavior.

```
33ae817a1ff4_add_kubernetes_resource_checkpointing.py
86770d1215c0_add_kubernetes_scheduler_uniqueness.py
```

Both the files are migration files using alembic and sqlalchemy libraries I found that following sqlalchemy code written in file 33ae817a1ff4_add_kubernetes_resource_checkpointing.py

```
def upgrade():

    columns_and_constraints = [
        sa.Column("one_row_id", sa.Boolean, server_default=sa.true(), primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("resource_version", sa.String(255))
    ]

    conn = op.get_bind()

    # alembic creates an invalid SQL for mssql dialect
    if conn.dialect.name not in ('mssql'):
        columns_and_constraints.append(sa.CheckConstraint("one_row_id", name="kube_resource_version_one_row_id"))

    table = op.create_table(
        RESOURCE_TABLE,
        *columns_and_constraints
    )

    op.bulk_insert(table, [
        {"resource_version": ""}
    ])
```

is interpreted into following SQL query which is not correct

```
CREATE TABLE  kube_resource_version (one_row_id BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT
true,  resource_version VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (one_row_id), 
CONSTRAINT kube_resource_version_one_row_id CHECK (one_row_id),  CHECK(one_row_id IN (0, 1))
```

Instead the SQL query should be some what like this

```
CREATE TABLE  kube_resource_version (one_row_id BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT
true,  resource_version VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (one_row_id), 
CONSTRAINT kube_resource_version_one_row_id CHECK (one_row_id IN (0, 1)))
```

The link provided by 'skadya' was helpful I got the system to work after making the changes in the code of the two above mentioned files.

you simple need to change the following code from

```
if conn.dialect.name not in ('mssql'):
columns_and_constraints.append(
sa.CheckConstraint("one_row_id", name="kube_resource_version_one_row_id"))
```

to

```
if conn.dialect.name not in ('mssql', 'mysql'):
columns_and_constraints.append(
sa.CheckConstraint("one_row_id", name="kube_resource_version_one_row_id")
```